# Validation of ml-model with highly imbalanced labels

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, validation

I'm currently working on a project which is facing highly imbalanced class labels. So let's say we have 1000 good labels and 5 bad labels. At the moment I'm not sure how long i have to collect data to verify the algorithm. Im working in a business environment and we have to ensure that the algorithm is really detecting bad labels. For training we use different Methods to solve the problem of imbalanced data (up/downsampling and semi supervised learning). Nevertheless we are currently not sure how we can validate that the algorithm works. So how should the test set look like :

```
In Terms of Size
In Terms of label distribution
In minimum amount of label per group (min. good labels & min. bad labels)
```

I tried to do some calculation for the sample size with random picking for a specific confidence intervall. (Like mentioned here: Sample Size Determination) So the sample should be "representativ" but can we trust the performance validation if the sample set only contains e.g. 5 bad labels.

Example:

Sample Size for an unlimited population with Confidence Intervall 95%, Margin of Error 5% ==> 384

If we take a closer look at this sample these 384 only contain 2 bad labels. So I don't think i can trust the performance metrics of the algorithm. (Which is predicting both bad labels correctly)

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Since you seem determined to catch as many "bad" labels as you can, why not just call everything a "bad" label? (Yes, I recognize that this is ridiculous, but how you respond will guide our advice.) // If you just have five instances of that "bad" class, you likely do not have enough data to do much.

Comment: It was only an example for the ratio of the problem. Currently we have around 30.000 labeled datasets with ~500 bad labels and there is a costly way to gather more labels. Nevertheless i want to know how many "bad" labels i need in a test set to make statistical statemens.

Comment: It is also a generell question of how a test set has to look like if you want to reliabel test an algorithm on it.

Comment: In addition of course we also have problems to check these false positives. So not only recall is key and a good precision should also be achieved